# Filter statement precedence (specially with joins) in Sequel

Tags: mysql, ruby, join, sequel

DB[:Table1].filter(condition_1).right_join(DB[:Table2].filter(condition_2),
join_condition).sql

Applies "filter(condition_1)" on the *result of right join* where as I
want the *right join to happen after this filter* has been applied on
DB[:Table1].
Both gives very different results to me.

How can I achieve this? I am just not able to think out a way to do
this (neither can I find anything in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

You want [Dataset#from_self](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-from_self):

```ruby
DB[:Table1].
  filter(condition_1).
  from_self.
  right_join(
    DB[:Table2].filter(condition_2),
    join_condition
  ).
  sql
```